# Javascript code for Autocomplete/suggest function for a textbox

Tags: 2013, javascript, jquery

I have a question with around 1000 possible choices (we need to know a email in a  share point list). Because a drop down list would be to long, we would let the users submit their answer in a text box and integrate a auto-complete/suggest function to prevent spelling errors.(textbox name like txtemail)

Comment: Using JQuery and SP Services, Explained in below link https://jsharepoint.wordpress.com/2017/05/24/auto-complete-control-using-sp-services/

Answer (score 3):

Use Taxonomyfields. There the user can write text and gets a autocomplete function out of the box

Answer (score 1):

The @Leopold answer is very good as OOTB solution. If you want to customize it you can use CSR (client side rendering) and implement autocomplete using Javascript. Here is similar sample or autocomplete using CSR:

http://cassy.be/site/sharepoint-2013-jquery-autocomplete-instead-of-contenttype-dropdown/